# What systems are currently in place to keep track of US money supply?

Tags: money-supply

What systems are currently in place to keep track of US money supply? For example, blockchain technology can be used to keep track of transactions on the Bitcoin network, and you can mathematically prove the existence of each bitcoin, and "track" its ownership on the network. What systems, if any, do we currently have in place to track and verify US currency? Where are the "whitepapers" for these systems located?

Answer (score 2):

In the US, The Treasury Department and The Federal Reserve (aka "The Fed") jointly act to control large parts of the money supply in a variety of ways, and thus keeps track of this and reports much of the information in their official statistics. The Treasury Department print and destroys money through the various currency mints it runs in the US - but actually printing up money and banging out coins is only a part of the total money supply.

The most direct cash-like parts of the money supply in the US is [reported by The Fed in their official statistics](https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h6/current/default.htm), called M1. The Fed provides this definition:

> M1 consists of (1) currency outside the U.S. Treasury, Federal Reserve
>   Banks, and the vaults of depository institutions; (2) traveler's
>   checks of nonbank issuers; (3) demand deposits at commercial banks
>   (excluding those amounts held by depository institutions, the U.S.
>   government, and foreign banks and official institutions) less cash
>   items in the process of collection and Federal Reserve float; and (4)
>   other checkable deposits (OCDs), consisting of negotiable order of
>   withdrawal (NOW) and automatic transfer service (ATS) accounts at
>   depository institutions, credit union share draft accounts, and demand
>   deposits at thrift institutions. Seasonally adjusted M1 is constructed
>   by summing currency, traveler's checks, demand deposits, and OCDs,
>   each seasonally adjusted separately.

M2 is the broader definition of they money supply, which The Fed tracks and defines as:

> M2 consists of M1 plus (1) savings deposits (including money market
>   deposit accounts); (2) small-denomination time deposits (time deposits
>   in amounts of less than $100,000), less individual retirement account
>   (IRA) and Keogh balances at depository institutions; and (3) balances
>   in retail money market mutual funds, less IRA and Keogh balances at
>   money market mutual funds. Seasonally adjusted M2 is constructed by
>   summing savings deposits, small-denomination time deposits, and retail
>   money funds, each seasonally adjusted separately, and adding this
>   result to seasonally adjusted M1.

While M1 is probably the part of the money supply most people think of when they hear money, it is actually only about 1/4th of a broader definition! Using the stats for June 2019, M1 is counted as 3,831.7 billion dollars, while the M2 is 14,755.1 billion dollars.

The Fed used to use an even broader definition which included "large-denomination time deposits, repurchase agreements (RPs), and Eurodollars", but in 2006 [The Fed announced that they would no longer report such statistics](https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h6/discm3.htm), stating they had not used them to make economic policy decisions for some time anyway and that it "does not appear to convey any additional information about economic activity that is not already embodied in M2". However, other central banks around the world still keep track of and report numbers like the M3, but no such official stats are used in the US.

Additional statistical models are kept privately by banks and investment funds, posted in newsletters like that of [Shadow Government Statistics](http://www.shadowstats.com/alternate_data/money-supply-charts), and others, but the official numbers are through The Fed.

As to verifying US currency, that is handled by the Secret Service (for investigating counterfeiting) and The Fed Fed for [testing/examining/verifying that notes are in good condition and authentic](https://www.federalreserve.gov/faqs/how-long-is-the-life-span-of-us-paper-money.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The Feds are the only institution that creates (or destroys) money, and they surely have a ledger where they note down how much they printed. That's all that is needed to know the exact total at any time.

Note that borrowing seems to increase the total amount of money all people together have, but that is not true - someone gets the borrowed money, but someone else also gives it so he has less. Also, borrowing would also work with bitcoin etc. - it is not a business yet, but it could be.

Comment: Borrowing seems to increase the total amount of money when it's a bank borrowing from you, and everyone you interact with accepts (digital) bank certificates as payment :)